# On pointwise bounded subsequences of a convergent sequence in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

When trying to rigorously formulate a proof presented to me during a PDE seminar I came across the following difficulty:

Let $(u_n) \subset H_0^1 (\Omega)$ be a bounded sequence such that $u_n \to u$ weakly in $H_0^1$ and $u_n \to u$ strongly in $L^p$ for $p$ such that $H_0^1 (\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^p (\Omega)$ compactly holds. Let $g$ be regular and such that
$$     |g (x, u)| \le C ( 1 + |u|^p ) $$
In order to prove (through some form the dominated convergence theorem) that $g(x,u_n) \to g(x,u)$ weakly in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ the following statement was made:

''If $u_n \to u$ on $L^p$ then there exists a subsequence $(u_n)$ such that $u_n \to u$ a.e $\Omega$ and a function $h \in L^1 (\Omega)$ such that $|u_n| \le h$ a.e $\Omega$''

I could not find the above statement anywhere (and it would be a wonderful addition to the Dominated Convergence Theorem) so I believe it must be wrong. Even if it where true, does anybody how to conclude the proof?

Thank you ever so much,

D

Comment: The "..." statement is true if $\Omega$ has finite measure, otherwise you should require $h\in L^p(\Omega)$.

Comment: Thank you! Could you name a reference?

Comment: You might see this as a by-product of the completeness theorem for $L^p$-spaces. At least, that's the way this result is presented on Rudin's R&CA

Comment: I found (3.11 on Rudin) that Cauchy sequence has a pointwise convergent subsequence. Were you referring to that? What bugs me is actually the uniformly pointwise bounded part. Any clues?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mentioned. You can recover the result you want from the proof of the main theorem there. If you are in a hurry have a look at Lieb & Loss's "Analysis", 2nd ed., theorem 2.7.

Comment: Take a look in theorem 4.9 from Brezis book: http://books.google.com.br/books/about/Functional_Analysis_Sobolev_Spaces_and_P.html?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $u_n \to u$ in $L^p$, by going to a subsequence, without loss of generality we may suppose that $\|u-u_n\|_p \le 2^{-n}$.  Let $h = \sup_n |u_n|$.  Then
$$ |h| \le |u| + \sum_{n=1}^\infty |u-u_n| ,$$
and hence
$$ \|h\|_p \le \|u\|_p + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|u-u_n\|_p < \infty .$$
If the measure of $\Omega$ is finite, this implies $h \in L^1$.